# Why is the Visible property not correctly updated in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, user-controls, visibility, scrollbars

Sometimes my UserControl's Visible property does not get updated correctly. It happens at my app's boot time, in OnFontChanged, fired from inside InitializeComponent, probably because some other stuff has not been set up yet. I just can't find out what.

[image]

`vScrollBar` is a UserControl and is inside another UserControl. Apparently, this only happens when trying to set the value to true.
`vScrollBar` already has its handle created, as a watch on IsHandleCreated says it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may still show false if the Form has not loaded.  Try setting it in the Form's OnLoad event.

Comment: Actual practical solution, Thx !

Answer (score 8):

Reading the Visible property gives you the actual visibility state of the control, not the 'intended' state.  Which will always be false in the InitializeComponent() method, the form or control isn't visible yet until *after* the Load event runs.  It will also be false if the container control isn't visible.

Comment: Wow, it's really easy to introduce bugs this way. I set Visible and put it in an if() in the next line, thinking it would be the value I just set it to. Evil stuff!

Comment: @atticae: The fact that Microsoft did something a certain way in .net doesn't always mean it was a good idea. It would seem that Microsoft couldn't decide whether to have a property which says whether it's possible to see something, or whether something allows itself to be seen; actually, properties would have been useful if they'd been given different names, but for whatever reason Microsoft decided to have a property called `Visible` whose getter returns the first thing and whose setter controls the second. Some 1970's computers had such problems in their designs, but people never learn...