# Setting Webcontrol Properties using Public Properties in Usercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I recently discovered that setting the visible property on a asp:button in my usercontrol does not always work by setting it thru a public property in my usercontrol (See [Why is the Visible property not correctly updated in a UserControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780140/why-is-the-visible-property-not-correctly-updated-in-a-usercontrol) ).  I'm used to setting my webcontrol properties thru public properties, but is there a standard or best practice to setting webcontrol properties for my usercontrol?

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
public partial class MyUserControl: System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    public bool IsVisible
    {
        set{MyButton.Visible = value;}
    }


    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyButton.Visible)
        {
            trButtons.Visible = true;
            //do something
            //MyButton.Visible is always false, even when it is assigned true thru the 
            //public property above, when the <tr> element in the form has Visible = "false"
        }
    }
}
```

Designer

```
 <table>
     <tr runat="server" id="trButtons" visible="true">
         <td>                
            <asp:Button ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="The Button" /> 
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I guess it is because of the page lifecycle.

Comment: What's the problem here? Is `Visibility` not being set to "True"?

Comment: dynamic properties aren't always working. Try visibility in Page_PreInit method of the life cycle.