# Public Property keeps changing it's value by itself

Tags: vb.net

This value needs to be `.visible = True` but...

```
    Public Property Active_bool As Boolean
    Get
        Return btn_Begin.Visible
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        btn_Begin.Visible = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I can't change my value in properties with the drop down box. It literally won't select True! So I have to change the code in the designer.vb but as soon as I view my form1 designer the values change back to False!

Is there maybe a way to set a default value to this property?

The property is meant to see if a button on a UserControl is visible or not. If it's visible then it will initiate a sub.

```
Private Sub btn_Start_All_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Start_All.Click
        Dim allActiveUserControls =
            From uc_Index In Controls.OfType(Of LapTimerGUI)()
        Where uc_Index.Active_bool
        For Each User_Control In allActiveUserControls
            User_Control.Start_Race()
        Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the Visible property not correctly updated in a UserControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780140/why-is-the-visible-property-not-correctly-updated-in-a-usercontrol)

Comment: Similar question yes, but not duplicate.

Comment: Dont rely on controls property because that force you to make the control visible to outer world. That control for sure will be set visible/enabled to true/false depending on some business rules. You have to stick on that rules in your system to take such decisions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this but i have to ask what is the environment ( Winform, WebForm) and what is the purpose of this property?

```
dim _isEnabled = true
Public Property IsEnabled As Boolean
    Get
        Return _isEnabled 
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _isEnabled = value
        btn_Begin.Visible = _isEnabled 
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: Thanks mate you helped me get my answer :)

Comment: @AmatureCoder: If the above answer was helpful, please don't forget to accept & upvote.